# python 3.7.3 - concurent.futures wait trouble

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrent.futures

I'm a beginner in python multithreading more precisely ThreadPoolExecutor, and I'm here to ask you about it. I'm currently working with concurrent.futures module and I'm stuck with the waiting event. My programm go over the waiting event and finnish the execution without printing the final values of each funcitons returned. Can someone explain me why, pls ? :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# module principal utilise concurent.futures pour executer 2 tacheds en parallele

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import shutil
import time
import threading



def function_AB():
    print("execution A_B")
    time.sleep(10)
    result_ab = "finish A_B"
    resultat_cd = Task_2.result(None)
    print(resultat_cd)
    return result_ab


def function_CD():
    print("execution C_D")
    time.sleep(3)
    result_cd = "finish C_D"
    resultat_ab = Task_1.result()
    print(resultat_ab)
    return result_cd


def main():
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)
    #submit = ne ferme pas explictement le pool comparer au with ThreadPoolExecutor() /
    # appel non bloquant programme principal traite l'impression de la déclaration immédiatement et se bloque jusqu'à ce que tous les threads aient terminé 
    Task_1 = executor.submit(function_AB)
    Task_2 = executor.submit(function_CD)
    print(Task_1)
    print(Task_2)
    #permet de bloquer les threads jusqu'à la fin de leur exécution
    executor.shutdown(wait=True)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    main()
    print("Temps execution : {}".format(time.time() - start))
```

Comment: In `function_AB` you are waiting for the result of the future that is created by running `function_AB` in a different thread. Is that intentional? If I read the documentation correctly, that should *never* finish. I'm actually kind of surprised it doesn't blow up...

Comment: No it wasn't, I was just testing some kind of things to better understood how does result() works

The thing is that if I tried using 
'''
def function_AB():
    print("execution A_B")
    time.sleep(10)
    resultat_cd = Task_2.result()
    print(type(resultat_cd))
    print("blabla")
    return result_ab
'''
The result is the same, it doesn't show or print the rest of the code like "finish C_D"  as I wished, and  I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, task 1 is waiting on the result of the `Future`  for task 2, while task 2 is waiting on the result of the `Future` for for task 1. This is a typical [deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock).

Look at the documentation for `Future.result()` (emphasis mine):

> If timeout is not specified or None, **there is no limit to the wait time**.

This means that both `Future`'s will keep waiting for each other. This means that nothing will be printed and the process will *never* finish. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so when I changed with timeout an exception has occured, "name 'Task_2' is not defined", so is that possible to wait the execution of a programm from another thread or it's only possible to wait the result from the main() fonction?

Comment: These example threads do very little work. It could be that task 1 is already running before task 2 has been created, leading to the above error. This goes to show that waiting for a `Future` inside another `Future` can *easily* lead to different kinds of problems. If you look at the design of `concurrent.futures.Executor`, waiting for the result of a `Future` is *generally* done in the main thread or process.